# Apply Regular expression on output file

Tags: python

I have written a python script that dumps all versions in a text file. All versions are separated by '|' symbol.

I need to replace all versions starting with 3 with follwing condition

e.g 1) 3.7.0E should be replaced as 03.07.00E 
    2) 3.17.1E should be replaced as 03.17.01E

All single digit numbers should be replaced with 0

## My output file looks like

> 3.7.0E|3.7.1E|3.7.2E|3.7.3E|3.7.4E|3.7.5E|16.2.1|16.2.2|3.8.0E|16.3.1|16.3.2|16.3.3|16.3.1a|16.4.1|16.4.2|3.17.1E|3.7.11E

Comment: Users on SO are happy to help if you're stuck with implementing a solution. But we're not here to code for free or do random coding exercises.

Comment: This is where i am stuck . i am unable to append 0 to these single digit numbers

Comment: Please share your minimal code example, indicating which part you're having trouble with. As it stands now, readers can reasonably assume that you're expecting them to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Be careful that people don't take what you say literally: "replaced with 0" is not actually what you want, nor is "append 0". Append means put after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but it will do what you want:

```
import re

s = '3.7.0E|3.7.1E|3.7.2E|3.7.3E|3.7.4E|3.7.5E|16.2.1|16.2.2|3.8.0E|16.3.1|16.3.2|16.3.3|16.3.1a|16.4.1|16.4.2|3.17.1E|3.7.11E'

l = []

# split up based on pipe
for chunk in s.split('|'):
    if chunk.startswith('3'):
        new_chunk = ''

        # split up based on period
        for piece in chunk.split('.'):
            try:
                # if there's a letter, exception will be thrown
                x = int(piece)
                new_chunk += '0{}.'.format(x) if x < 10 else '{}.'.format(x)

            except:
                n = int(re.search('\d+', piece).group(0))
                letter = re.search('\w', piece).group(0)
                new_chunk += '0{}{}'.format(n, letter) if n < 10 else piece

        l.append(''.join(new_chunk))
    else:
        l.append(chunk)

new_s = '|'.join([p for p in l])
print(new_s)
```

The value of `new_s` will be: `'03.07.00E|03.07.01E|03.07.02E|03.07.03E|03.07.04E|03.07.05E|16.2.1|16.2.2|03.08.00E|16.3.1|16.3.2|16.3.3|16.3.1a|16.4.1|16.4.2|03.17.01E|03.07.11E'`.

Comment: Thanks for the output but only versions starting with 3 should be replaced

Comment: @SHIVASRAINA sorry, didn't see that. I've updated the code to add a simple check for that.

Comment: Thank you so much colin.

Comment: @ Colin if the numbers dont end with E then it still appends them with E because in code '0{}E'.format(n) If there is a string 3.4.0S it makes it 03.04.00E

Comment: Yep that's right, you can just extract the letter in the same way that you extract number `n` with regex.

Comment: How can i keep my letter same

Comment: @ Colin the output now becomes like this   03.07.000|03.07.011|03.07.022|03.07.033|03.07.044|03.07.055|16.2.1|16.2.2|03.08.000|16.3.1|16.3.2|16.3.3|16.3.1a|16.4.1|16.4.2|03.17.011|03.07.11E